Ошибка при установке библиотек через pip
nessie27@nessie27-MS-7A38:~$ pip install numpy
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.12/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.

Операционная система Ubuntu 22.04

Вам как бы намекают - не надо ломать систему установкой в неё левых пакетов, создайте изолированное виртуальное окружение и устанавливайте всё внутри него

Это вы про какие пакеты?

Ну например про тот самый numpy, установкой которого вы попытались сломать систему

Вкратце, что тут написано: ваша система не разрешает вам глобально устанавливать пакеты через pip install. Если очень нужно глобально - можно попробовать через apt install python3-имя-пакета. Но в целом - используйте виртуальное окружение. То что в предпоследней строке написано - не советую.

это теперь у всех так или только на LInux

Это теперь на некоторых дистрибутивах Linux

Если используете PyCharm это можно сделать в графическом интерфейсе через меню Add New Interpreter. Которое обычно находится в правом нижнем углу.

Введите в Терминале:
python3 -m venv myenv
source .bin/activate/

После этого все заработает.
